# Hi, Planning for a scheduled shutdown in client windows machine via group policy. Can any one share the steps to follow?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

Planning for a scheduled shutdown in client windows machine via group policy. Can any one share the steps to follow?

Answer (score 1):

For the most important steps you can follow:

1. Open a Group Policy Object that is targeted to your computers and go to Computer Configurations > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Scheduled Tasks
2. Create a new Scheduled Task to run with the shutdown.exe command.
3. There are two text boxes to fill in the path and values. The first one is for the command, there you go with
   C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe under that, there's another text box you can put arguments in. There you type -f -s

Full info below:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1317f73d-0d78-461a-b0e4-684d32040429/schedule-a-shutdown-task-using-gpo

There are a lot of approaches, but you can try this one.

Comment: Thanks, Will check this way.

Comment: Hi I have tired the method. But it isn't working

Comment: Did you try with the SYSTEM account?